# How to do a recursive Diff of a file abiding the subfolder structure in Unix

Tags: linux, file, unix, directory, diff

I want to do a recursive diff in which if a file is encountered, it should consider the file which is in the same folder structure in both the directories which are compared.

Example:

```
diff -ry Dir1 Dir2
```

> Dir1 -> subfolder1 -> file1.txt, Dir2 -> subfolder2 -> file1.txt, Dir2
>   -> subfolder1 -> file1.txt
>
> > In the above case, the recursive diff should only compare files
> >     "subfolder1 -> file1.txt" of both Dir1 and Dir2. The path "subfolder2
> >     -> file1.txt" should be ignored as the folder structure is different. Anyone with bright ideas ?

Comment: That is how diff works already. What result are you getting that you're unhappy with?

Comment: In some cases, the "subfolder2 -> file1.txt" was also considered for comparision as a result of which the diff is showing changes in the complete file of "subfolder1 -> file1.txt". Is there any way like piping with ls or something to make it work perfectly.